# How do I change media list rendering?

Tags: entities

I'm new in Drupal 7, and I'd like to change the media list upload behavior, most precisely the way elements are displayed.

This is what I have now.

> [image: screenshot]

This is what I want.

> [image: screenshot]

I searched all over the web, but I only found tutorials to make custom field widgets, or something (useless for me).